# How to connect OSGi to SAP?

Tags: java, osgi, jco

I need to connect Adobe CQ5 (OSGi based CMS) to SAP server to get some information from SAP. I don't have access to SAP server, meaning I cannot install anything there.

According to what I've found out it's possible to connect Java application to SAP server using one of the following methods.

**1) Through Web services** 
Unfortunately, it doesn't fit our needs because additional configuration on the server side is required.

**2) Through SAP Java Connector** 
According to this page I can connect to SAP server using JCo without any configuration on the server side. http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/8b/912229a9e611d6b28f00508b6b8a93/content.htm

Here it is described how to install the SAP Java Connector http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/47/80f671ee6e4b41b63c0fe46bd6e4f8/content.htm

But it uses not only .jar but also some .dll. But AFAIK .dll is a Windows thing, OSGi knows nothing about .dlls.

So, how to connect OSGi to SAP server without additional SAP-side configuration? Is it possible to do it with SAP JCo? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the SAP JCo in an OSGi environment. Take a look at [RCER](http://rcer.sourceforge.net) - although that specific project is somewhat dormant now, I have provided some tools to bundle the JCo up as an Eclipse Plugin (which is little more than an OSGi bundle). You have to take some precautions thought so that the class loader is able to access the native library - you won't be able to get any communication going without that library. RCER uses fragments to add the platform-dependent library while the host plug-in contains the platform-independent jar.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was very helpful, as thanks to it I've found out that it's possible and it gave me hope. Eventually I chose to include the native libraries using Bundle-NativeCode declaration of OSGi bundle, and it worked well: http://holistictendencies.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/bundle-nativecode-using-platform-specific-dlls-from-osgi/